# Trabajo de algoritmo 1

Tags: java, algoritmos

Tengo este ejercicio y me da problemas:

> Dados dos vectores ordenados v1 y v2 de dimensiones n1 y n2 respectivamente, ordenados y sin elementos repetidos que genere un vector v3 ordenado que contenga los elementos de los vectores v1 y v2 
>   v1={1,3,5,7}
>   v2 ={2,4,6}
>
> Resultado Buscado: V3 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

```
public static  int [] obtenervector(int []v1,int []v2){

        int largo= v1.length + v2.length;
        int[] v3 =new int[largo];
        int i=0,j=0;
       // IMPLEMENTE LO QUE FALTA 
       //-----------------------
       //----------------------
        return v3;
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
public static  int [] obtenervector(int []v1,int []v2){
     int largo=v1.length+v2.length;
    int v3[] = new int[largo];

    System.arraycopy(v1, 0, v3, 0, v1.length);
     System.arraycopy(v2, 0, v3, v1.length, v2.length);

     for(int h=1; h<largo; h++) {
        int k=h;
       while(k>0 && v3[k]<v3[k-1] ){
            int aux = v3[k];
          v3[k] = v3[k-1];
            v3[k-1] = aux;
           k--;
       }
     }
     return v3;  


}
```

Andar anda, pero no es el metodo que busca el profesor...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a realizar el [tour] y así ganarás tu primera medalla. Además, te invito a leer [ask] y puedas entender cómo realizar tu pregunta. En cuanto a lo que haz probado, dices: *Ya probe todo*, ¿podrías subir el código de lo que has intentado? Saludos

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el método que *busca el profesor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución sería utilizar la función estática `sort()` de la clase `java.util.Arrays`.

```
public static int[] obtenervector(int[] v1, int[] v2) {
    int largo = v1.length + v2.length; 
    int[] v3 = new int[largo];
    System.arraycopy(v1, 0, v3, 0, v1.length);
    System.arraycopy(v2, 0, v3, v1.length, v2.length);
    java.util.Arrays.sort(v3);
    return v3;
}
```

Otras serían la implementación manual de algorítmos de ordenamiento como **BubbleSort**, **MergeSort**, **QuickSort**, etc.
Como dato útil, el método `sort()` de la clase `Arrays` utiliza un **QuickSort**.

Pero para este caso en específico, y sin necesidad de utilizar ningún algoritmo de ordenamiento, una solución sería la siguiente:

```
public static int[] obtenervector(int[] v1, int[] v2) {
        int[] v3 = new int[v1.length + v2.length];
        int v1Pos = 0;
        int v2Pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v3.length; i++) {
            if (v1Pos < v1.length) {
                if (v2Pos < v2.length) {
                    if (v1[v1Pos] <= v2[v2Pos]) {
                        v3[i] = v1[v1Pos];
                        v1Pos++;
                    } else {
                        v3[i] = v2[v2Pos];
                        v2Pos++;
                    }
                } else {
                    v3[i] = v1[v1Pos];
                    v1Pos++;
                }
            } else if (v2Pos < v2.length) {
                v3[i] = v2[v2Pos];
                v2Pos++;
            }
        }
        return v3;
}
```

Comment: El profesor busca que usemos un metodo sin usar los arraycopy y sin ordenar, osea, en el v3 ir poniendo posicion 0 de v1+posicion 0 del v2, osea armar el v3 intercalando v1 y v2, no encuentro como hcerlo

Comment: Ya realize la edición, creo que esto es lo que tratabas de explicar.

Comment: el ultimo valor da 0 , osea esta perfecto pero hay un problema en el ultimo, me da todo 0!

Comment: Lo arregle, no lo habia probado para un grupo de casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionado y corregido :P!

Answer (score 1):

He evitado incluir la parte en la que pasamos los datos de V1 y V2 a V3.
El método es sencillo pero rápido y efectivo ya que comparamos un elemento de V3[i] con todos los siguientes V3[j] hasta que encuentra uno más pequeño. En ese caso hacemos un intercambio (swap) de los datos. Una vez terminado el bucle todos los números estarán ordenados.

```
int v3_tmp;
for (int i = 0; i <= v3.length-2; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j <= v3.length-1; i++) {
        If (V3[i] > V3[j]) {
            v3_tmp = V3[i];
            V3[i] = V3[j];
            V3[j] = v3_tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

El mismo código en VBA Excel funciona perfectamente aunque hay que hacer una aclaración. En VBA UBound nos devuelve la posición del último elemento mientras que v3.length nos devuelve la longitud del array. Por eso en el ejemplo de arriba he puesto  v3.length-2 mientras que abajo es UBound(V3)-1

```
For i = 0 To UBound(V3) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(V3)
        If V3(i) > V3(j) Then
            v3_tmp = V3(i)
            V3(i) = V3(j)
            V3(j) = v3_tmp
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: me dan 0 todos los valores con el ejemplo primero, aunque entendi a lo del swap, voy a ver si lo modoficio,gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Yo, cuando me salen resultados raros incluyo líneas adicionales para mostrar los supuestos datos erroneos. Por ejemplo, podrias añadir entre estas dos líneas algo así:

Comment: Después de    If (V3[i] > V3[j]) {     la línea:    System.out.println(V3[i];      con ello verias si V3[i] tiene los valores correctos. Si los tiene pon otra línea al final del bucle para ver si hace el swap. Si V3 muestra siempre 0 es que el problema está más arriba.